# Why doesn't this Ruby program return off heap memory to the operating system?

Tags: ruby, memory-management, mri

I am trying to understand when memory allocated off the Ruby heap gets returned to the operating system. I understand that Ruby never returns memory allocated to it's heap but I am still not sure about the behaviour of off heap memory. i.e. those objects that don't fit into a 40 byte RVALUE.

Consider the following program that allocates some large strings and then forces a major GC.

```
require 'objspace'

STRING_SIZE = 250

def print_stats(msg)
  puts '-------------------'
  puts msg
  puts '-------------------'
  puts "RSS: #{`ps -eo rss,pid | grep #{Process.pid} | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1,"KB";}'`}"
  puts "HEAP SIZE: #{(GC.stat[:heap_sorted_length] * 408 * 40)/1024} KB"
  puts "SIZE OF ALL OBJECTS: #{ObjectSpace.memsize_of_all/1024} KB"
end

def run
  print_stats('START WORK')
  @data=[]
  600_000.times do
    @data <<  " "  * STRING_SIZE
  end
  print_stats('END WORK')
  @data=nil
end

run
GC.start
print_stats('AFTER FORCED MAJOR GC')
```

Running this program with Ruby 2.2.3 on MRI it produces the following output. After a forced major GC, the heap size is as expected but RSS has not decreased significantly.

```
-------------------
START WORK
-------------------
RSS: 7036 KB
HEAP SIZE: 1195 KB
SIZE OF ALL OBJECTS: 3172 KB
-------------------
END WORK
-------------------
RSS: 205660 KB
HEAP SIZE: 35046 KB
SIZE OF ALL OBJECTS: 178423 KB
-------------------
AFTER FORCED MAJOR GC
-------------------
RSS: 164492 KB
HEAP SIZE: 35046 KB
SIZE OF ALL OBJECTS: 2484 KB
```

Compare these results to the following results when we allocate one large object instead of many smaller objects.

```
def run
  print_stats('START WORK')
  @data = " " * STRING_SIZE * 600_000
  print_stats('END WORK')
  @data=nil
end

-------------------
START WORK
-------------------
RSS: 7072 KB
HEAP SIZE: 1195 KB
SIZE OF ALL OBJECTS: 3170 KB
-------------------
END WORK
-------------------
RSS: 153584 KB
HEAP SIZE: 1195 KB
SIZE OF ALL OBJECTS: 149064 KB
-------------------
AFTER FORCED MAJOR GC
-------------------
RSS: 7096 KB
HEAP SIZE: 1195 KB
SIZE OF ALL OBJECTS: 2483 KB
```

Note the final RSS value. We seem to have freed all the memory we allocated for the big string.

I am not sure why the second example releases the memory but the first example doesn't as they are both allocating memory off the Ruby heap. This is one [reference](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/ewong/005-Avoiding-system-calls.html) that could provide an explanation but I would be interested in explanations from others.

> Releasing memory back to the kernel also has a cost. User space memory
>   allocators may hold onto that memory (privately) in the hope it can be
>   reused within the same process and not give it back to the kernel for
>   use in other processes.

Comment: Subscribing to this thread. I'm *very* interested in this as well.

Comment: The fundamental difference is in 1st example, where 600k *new* objects are created, in the second only one. Although the total size of *referenced* data is the same, the first example requires 600 thousand times more slots for referencing objects (which are probably never or much later reclaimed to OS).

Comment: I'd suggest following [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-uses-memory/) and linked [explanation](http://rocket-science.ru/hacking/2013/12/17/ruby-memory-pitfalls/) of `RVALUE`s. I'm not sure if they are quite correct, only Koichi aka ko1 himself may know. Or some strongly determined enthusiast, analysing Ruby sources.

Answer (score 3):

@joanbm has a very good point here. His referenced [article explains this pretty well](http://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-uses-memory/) :

Ruby's GC releases memory gradually, so when you do GC on 1 big chunk of memory pointed by 1 reference it releases it all, but when there is a lot of references, the GC will releases memory in smaller chuncks.

Several calls to `GC.start` will release more and more memory in the 1st example.

---

Here are 2 orther articles to dig deeper :

- http://thorstenball.com/blog/2014/03/12/watching-understanding-ruby-2.1-garbage-collector/
- https://samsaffron.com/archive/2013/11/22/demystifying-the-ruby-gc